# How to model state space for complex valued system correctly in SIMULINK (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab, complex, state-space, integration, simulink

When trying to use the default state-space model block, if there is a **complex number** valued in the matrices, there will be an error

[image: default state-space model block]

---

To resolve that, firstly I need to look at pseudo reference model of state space on the internet
[image]

Then, create my own state-space block as a new subsystem

[image]

u is for input
y is for output
x is the state variable as an output (for sensing use, such as full state feedback)

And here is the inside

[image]

---

Now the problem is that,

1. The **IC (Initial Condition)** block cannot simulate what **lsim**
   can done in matlab code, there must be an exponential decay expected
   result for the unforced solution, but what I've got is that the
   initial condition only happened at the **exact t=0** and there is
   **no** exponential decay. 
    How do I solve it?
2. The **Integrator** and **IC** block cannot operate with complex valued 
   number, the input and must be separated manually into real and imaginary 
   part or magnitude and phase part and then joined together again. Is there
   any better way to operate them with complex valued number in simulink?
3. The **gain** block of A, B, C, and D matrix look ugly, I haven't been
   able to change it in the shape of rectangle box as my reference
   model above. Is there any way to change it?

Finally, if there is any better solution for my problem, such as pre-builtin complex valued state-space model, or better subsystem, I would be happy to know it

Comment: What do the `modal_in` blocks do?

Comment: @fibonatic sorry for messy writing, it's stands for `canonic_modal_initial`. I forgot to rename it, it's a vector for `initial codition x(0) for`

Comment: doesn't the integrator block have initial conditions as well?

Comment: I've also been thinking about that, but I'm confused whether it will be initial condition for input or for output of the integrator, xdot(0) or x(0). What we want obviously the x(0)

Comment: x(0), see [documentation](https://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/integrator.html).

Comment: @fibonatic It seems to be working right now, but considering it has two integrator for real and for imaginary x. Do I also need to separate the real and imaginary number of x(0)? The real part of x(0) for real integrator and the imaginary part x(0) for imaginary integrator?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the merging would not yield the intended complex valued state.

Answer (score 2):

You can split up the real and imaginary part of the state into their own seperate states. Namely by defining $x_r=\mathrm{Re}(x)$, $x_i=\mathrm{Im}(x)$, $A_r=\mathrm{Re}(A)$, $A_i=\mathrm{Im}(A)$, $u_r=\mathrm{Re}(u)$, $u_i=\mathrm{Im}(u)$, $B_r=\mathrm{Re}(B)$ and $B_i=\mathrm{Im}(B)$ then the differential equation can also be written as

$$
\dot{x}_r+i\,\dot{x}_i=(A_r+i\,A_i)(x_r+i\,x_i)+(B_r+i\,B_i)(u_r+i\,u_i)
$$

which when split into their real and imaginary part gives

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}_r \\ \dot{x}_i
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
A_r & -A_i \\
A_i & A_r
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_r \\ x_i
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
B_r & -B_i \\
B_i & B_r
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_r \\ u_i
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The output can be expressed using

$$
y=C\begin{bmatrix}
I & i\,I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_r \\ x_i
\end{bmatrix} + D\begin{bmatrix}
I & i\,I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_r \\ u_i
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: The u or input is located inside of Re and Im function. How do you separate it?

Comment: @Unknown123 I have updated my answer.